# Java parsing ADIF file

Tags: java, parsing, adif

ADIF format is described here: http://www.adif.org/ I'm trying to make Adif parser. Here is portion of Adif file to be parsed:

```
ADIF 2 Export from eQSL.cc 
Received eQSLs for IZ1080SWL 
for QSOs between 10-Aug-2015 and 31-Dec-2035 
Generated on Sunday, October 18, 2015 at 00:48:50 AM UTC
<PROGRAMID:21>eQSL.cc DownloadInBox
<ADIF_Ver:1>2 
<EOH>
<CALL:6>RA1QEA<QSO_DATE:8:D>20150829<TIME_ON:4>0455<BAND:3>30m<MODE:2>CW<RST_SENT:3>SWL<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<APP_EQSL_AG:1>Y<GRIDSQUARE:6>lo19aq<EOR>
<CALL:5>F6HKA<QSO_DATE:8:D>20150910<TIME_ON:4>0400<BAND:3>80m<MODE:2>CW<RST_SENT:3>swl<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<QSLMSG:34>Thanks for the SWL report. 73 Bert<APP_EQSL_AG:1>Y<GRIDSQUARE:6>JN05ot<EOR>
<CALL:5>DL5ZL<QSO_DATE:8:D>20150912<TIME_ON:4>2229<BAND:3>30m<MODE:2>CW<RST_SENT:3>599<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<QSLMSG:28>tks, paper qsl is on the way<APP_EQSL_AG:1>Y<GRIDSQUARE:6>JO51jl<EOR>
<CALL:5>4Z5ML<QSO_DATE:8:D>20150915<TIME_ON:4>0504<BAND:3>20m<MODE:2>CW<RST_SENT:3>599<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<APP_EQSL_AG:1>Y<GRIDSQUARE:4>km72<EOR>
```

I try this parser:

```
    public void read() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

    int intValue;
    boolean createToken = false;
    boolean createSize = false;
    StringBuffer token = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer size = new StringBuffer();
    Adif2Record record = new Adif2Record();


    while ((intValue = br.read()) != -1) {
        char cValue = (char)intValue;

        if (cValue == '\n') {
            continue;
        }
        if (cValue == '<') {
            createToken = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (cValue == ':') {
            createToken = false;
            createSize = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (cValue == '>') {
            if ("eor".equalsIgnoreCase(token.toString())) {
                records.add(record);
                record = new Adif2Record();
                token.setLength(0);
                size.setLength(0);
                continue;
            }
            createSize = false;
            createData(br, token.toString(), str2int(size.toString()), record);
            size.setLength(0);
            token.setLength(0);

        }

        if (createToken) {
            token.append(cValue);
        }
        if (createSize) {
            size.append(cValue);
        }
    }

}
```

but I end up only with one token "PROGRAMID" and the rest of file becomes data for this token. The portion before EOF token is a header and I would not like to slice it off completely but I don't understand why createSize is keeping true after PROGRAMID, according to idea it should reset to false after each loop. Can someone help?

Comment: `if (cValue == 'a') {} if (cValue == 'b') {} if (cValue == 'c') {}` looks like you could write this more readable as `switch (cValue) {case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing logic to handle the header. Basically the header seems to be allowed to contain text including `:` which means you have to add a check, it a tag is being parsed to the case where you get a `:` char.

Furthermore you need to handle data types appropriately, since otherwise the type is simply appended to the size.

Also you should use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`, since the latter also does synchronisation which just decreases the performance in this case without providing any benefits.

The following code also replaces some of the `if`s with `switch` statements.

For simplicity it uses another record for the header data...

```
public static void createData(BufferedReader br, String token, int size, Adif2Record record) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int c = br.read();
        if (c == -1) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected end of input");
        }
        sb.appendCodePoint((char) c);
    }
    record.setData(token, sb.toString());
}

private List<Adif2Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

public void read() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

    int intValue;
    boolean createToken = false;
    boolean createSize = false;
    boolean createType = false;
    StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder size = new StringBuilder();
    Adif2Record record = new Adif2Record();

    while ((intValue = br.read()) != -1) {
        switch (intValue) {
            case '\n':
                break;
            case '<':
                createToken = true;
                break;
            case ':':
                if (createToken) {
                    // not in header
                    createToken = false;
                    createSize = true;
                } else if (createSize) {
                    createType = true;
                    createSize = false;
                }
                break;
            case '>':
                switch (token.toString().toLowerCase()) {
                    case "eor":
                    case "eoh":
                        records.add(record);
                        record = new Adif2Record();
                        break;
                    default:
                        createSize = false;
                        createType = false;
                        createData(br, token.toString(), str2int(size.toString()), record);
                }
                token.setLength(0);
                size.setLength(0);
                break;
            default:
                char cValue = (char) intValue;
                if (createToken) {
                    token.append(cValue);
                }
                if (createSize) {
                    size.append(cValue);
                }
                if (createType) {
                    // TODO
                }
        }

    }

}

private static int str2int(String s) {
    return s.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

```
public class Adif2Record {

    private final Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    public void setData(String key, String value) {
        data.put(key, value);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting concept of Adif2Record class I didnt think of using Map, but I use data in javafx tableview, so, I have over 100 defined string properties there with getters and setters. about str2int - some sizes are defined with integer and char e.g. dates are sized like '8D' which is basically means int 8 so, I have this there: <code>String intValue = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");</code> Where is this code from? do you have already some simple ADIF parser?

Comment: still doesnt work, keeps giving NullPointerException on method setCall in Adif2Record, even if I skip it it continues to throw this exception on every setter in Adif2Record

Comment: It didnt work because I didnt initiate fields in Adif2Record class, my fault